# Yielding Templates through Layout with Sinatra: Yields stringified version of my html

Tags: html, templates, sinatra, yield

Within a sinatra framework, I'm trying to yield a template, dashboard.haml, within a layout template: layout.haml. But when the page loads, a stringified version of the html appears, instead of the HTML itself. So it's clearly fetching the correct template, but I wonder why the html is being rendered as a string??

Here are the relevant code:

server.rb

```
 get '/:developer' do
  @workflow_audits = Auditor.new(params['developer']).workflow_audits
  haml :dashboard, :layout => :layout
 end
```

views/layout.haml

```
%html
  %head
    %title Workflow Stuff
    %link{ :rel => :stylesheet, :type => "text/scss", :href => "/stylesheets/dashboard.scss"}
    %script{ :src => "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" }

  %body
    %form{action: '/', method: 'post'}
      %label{for: 'developer'}Select a developer:
      %input{type: 'text', name: 'developer'}
      %input{type: 'submit', value: 'submit'}

    = yield
```

views/dashboard.haml

```
%ul.issue-list
   - @workflow_audits.each do |audit|
      %li.issue
        .issue-container.row
```

Comment: Hi emily, that works for me - which version of Ruby, Sinatra, Haml etc are you using?

Comment: Hey iain thanks for responding. It looks like I'm using Sinatra 1.4.5, HAML 4.0.5, and Ruby 2.0.0p481.

Comment: What happens if you use Bundler with sandboxing? e.g. install Bundler with `gem install bundler`, add Sinatra and Haml to a Gemfile, and install with `bundle install --binstubs --path=vendor` and then run the project with `bundle exec ruby server.rb`?

Answer (score 2):

You have an indentation issue in dashboard.haml. I removed the 3 spaces and tabs in your post and put two spaces everywhere, all errors went away and was able to get it working.

```
%ul.issue-list
  - @workflow_audits.each do |audit|
    %li.issue
      .issue-container.row
```